# After loading a plist into my tableview how do I pass the info to a 2nd view controller? (NSDictionary)

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I loaded my pList into a table view controller that segues to a view controller.  I can't figure out how to load the data corresponding to the cell tapped into a label on this view controller. The plist is an NSDictionary, by the way.

In viewDidLoad of the table view controller I have:

```
 NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                    pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"];


recipes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile]; 

courseKeys = [recipes allKeys];
```

I am not sure how to tell the label that the name of the recipe chosen was X so you display the ingredients for X.

Thanks for the help!

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget - a `UITableView` is a way to display your data. Once a user selects a row within a UITableView, you get notified of this via your `UITableViewDelegate` method (specifically `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`). You can use the indexPath to grab whatever data you need from whatever data structure you're working with (in your case, `NSDictionary`) and pass it on to whatever controller you are displaying next by implementing the `prepareForSegueue` method correctly. I would suggest defining a property in that next UIViewController and assigning it the data to be passed on in `prepareForSegueue`. I would however pay some thought as to wether you wish to pass a direct reference to the data or maybe a deep copy of it - it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish in that VC.

Comment: Thanks! I created a dictionary of recipes and want the name of the recipes to display in the table view cells, which currently works, and when clicked segues to a detail view of the chosen recipe.

Comment: How do I pass the corresponding value to the next view controller? I couldnt figure this out - im a beginner by the way.  I set up a property to accept the data but not sure what to add in prepareforsegue

Comment: Within prepareForSegueue you have a reference to the inbound view controller. This would be the place to assign it any data it needs.